# Медленная отработка инструкций CREATE (MySQL 5.6, InnoDB, Windows)

Tags: windows, innodb, mysql

Был бы благодарен за совет.

Есть приложение - по обработке входящих дампов из удаленного источника.
Приложение на лету создает под этот дамп временную БД, таблицы в ней (50-60 штук), вставляет данные, проводит с ними ряд служебных операций, "прибивает" временную БД и переходит к следующему дампу.

В приложении крайне критична производительность (время выполнения), и падение этой самой производительности обнаружили исключительно в момент отработки инструкций CREATE, на стороне сервера. На цикл одного только создания структуры уходит около 1+ минуты, причем сама вставка данных проходит в общем-то быстро. Затык именно на создании структуры БД и таблиц.

Подозреваю, что все упирается в тонкости реализации InnoDB, но к сожалению не являюсь специалистом в этой области. Возможно кто-то посоветует как можно ускорить этот процесс?

Платформа Windows x86/x64, MySQL 5.6, engine InnoDB.